# How to recieve request.getParameter("eventdetails") in spring using rest client or postman?

Tags: spring, web-services, jakarta-ee, rest-client, postman

I have following code :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/createEventWS", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
Map<String, Object> createEventWS(HttpServletRequest request) {
   request.getParameter("eventdetails");
}
```

I want eventdetails parameters using restclient or postman. How can I achieve that?

Thanks

Comment: Can you add your POST body here?

Comment: How do you have to post with your instruments or how do you have to handle this in your method?

Answer (score 0):

You can use @RequestParam annotation to get it.

```
Map<String, Object> createEventWS(@RequestParam("eventdetails") eventdetails) {

}
```